# Dynamic memory allocation for char***

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, calloc

I was trying to dynamically allocate memory for a char***.

```
char*** tas;
```

With char*** i want to describe a table of strings with 2 columns only.

Main problem i had trying to achieve that is not to compile the program but make it run without a segmentation fault.

The issue i think is the not proper use of realloc.
Checking man page of realloc/calloc/malloc

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
void *malloc(size_t size);
void *calloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size);
```

I found out that i have to generate the proper size_t vars to send to allocate functions.

The crucial lines of code for this are the following:

```
tas         = (char ***)realloc(tas,sizeof(char **)*(i+1));
tas[i]      = (char **)calloc(2,sizeof(char *));
tas[i][0]   = (char *)calloc(lenKey+1,sizeof(char));
tas[i][1]   = (char *)calloc(lenValue+1,sizeof(char));
++i;
```

With `tas` beeing the char***.

--------EDIT-------

Piece by piece I compiled an answer and i am posting the solution i found to the problem here.

Comment: If you ever find yourself writing `***`, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @user2357112 The above is for research purpose and there is nothing wrong into learning stuff... I know that struct are the same but i am trying to understand a bit more of allocation functions.

Comment: Being a 3-star C programmer is not a complient! If you need a multidimensional array, use one.

Comment: There could sometimes be a reason to use a ragged two-dimensional array, that is, `char**` instead of `char string_table[ROWS][COLUMNS]`, or `char *string_table[]`, but there really is never one to use `char***`. If the goal is to save memory on a sparse array, use a compressed sparse array format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so hard, you just need to keep your head clear.

First off, keep the general pattern in mind: To allocate an array of `n` elements of type `T`, use:

```
T * p = malloc(n * sizeof(T));
```

Then initialize the values `p[i]` for `i` in the range `[0, n)`, then de-initialize the elements when you're done, if necessary, and then release the array allocation with:

```
free(p);
```

---

Now just do this recursively for your array of arrays of strings, bearing in mind that a string is an array of characters, `m` rows of `n` columns of strings:

```
// allocate the table (the row pointers)
char *** tas = malloc(m * sizeof(char**));

for (size_t i = 0; i != m; ++i)
{
    // allocate each row (the row cells)
    tas[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
    for (size_t j = 0; j != n; ++j)
    {
        // initialize the row cell by allocating the string
        tas[i][j] = /* allocate string */
    }
}
```

And on the way back, to free everything:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i != m; ++i)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j != n; ++j)
    {
        free(tas[i][j]);  // free the string
    }

    free(tas[i]);         // free the row
}

free(tas);                // free the table
```

Answer (score 0):

A char*** is like a table of strings.

```
      R\C  ||---1-----|----2----|   
   |---1---||string11 |string12 |
   |---2---||string21 |string22 |
   |---3---||string31 |string32 |
   | ....  ||  .....     ...... |
   |-(N-1)-||str N-1.1|str N-1.2|
   |---N---||stringN1 |stringN2 |
```

Here is a demo source code with comments in order to understand how to achieve something like that:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void rellocateFunction(size_t lenKey, size_t lenValue);
void firstAllocateFunction(size_t lenKey, size_t lenValue);
int i=0;
char*** tas;

int main(){
    int j=0;
    size_t length1, length2; 
    char* stringN1=(char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    char* stringN2=(char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    while(1){
        printf("dragons\n");
        printf("MAIN: Enter string[%d][0]:",j); scanf("%s", stringN1);
        printf("MAIN: Enter string[%d][1]:",j); scanf("%s", stringN2);
        length1 = strlen(stringN1); // You need the length of the string to pass it as an argumnet to allocation functions
        length2 = strlen(stringN2); // Same as above comment
        if(j==0) firstAllocateFunction(length1,length2); // We cant start with the use of realloc. So here you are initiliazing the allocation with calloc only.
        else rellocateFunction(length1,length2); // When we already have entries in the table, we are going to use this function to allocate more memory for the new entries.
        strcpy(tas[j][0],stringN1);  // Population of char*** at row j and col 0
        strcpy(tas[j][1],stringN2);  // Population of char*** at row j and col 1
        j++;
        for (int c=0; c<j; c++) // Print the results
        {
            printf("tas[%d][0]:<%s>\n",c, tas[c][0]);
            printf("tas[%d][1]:<%s>\n",c, tas[c][1]);
        }
    } // Notice the forever ongoing loop... That's to test if the code works. Cancel the execution with ctrl+c
    return 0;
}

void firstAllocateFunction(size_t len1, size_t len2){ 
tas         = (char ***)calloc(1,sizeof(char **)); //One char*** pointer
tas[i]      = (char **)calloc(2,sizeof(char *));   //pointin to 2 char** 
tas[i][0]   = (char *)calloc(len1+1,sizeof(char)); //containing len1+1 
tas[i][1]   = (char *)calloc(len2+1,sizeof(char)); //and len2+1 elements of sizeof(char) bytes.
++i;
}

void rellocateFunction(size_t len1, size_t len2){
tas         = (char ***)realloc(tas,sizeof(char **)*(i+1)); //One more char***
tas[i]      = (char **)calloc(2,sizeof(char *));   ////////////////////
tas[i][0]   = (char *)calloc(len1+1,sizeof(char)); // Same as above //
tas[i][1]   = (char *)calloc(len2+1,sizeof(char)); ///////////////////
++i;
}
```

I used calloc, because i wanted to avoid using memset to init the strings. The rest are explained with comments.

Note that you have to allocate your memory for char*** the first time using a different function() than the rest of the times that you will basically reallocating the memory of char***.

Warning. The code above does not implement the free() function (which is highly recommended to. So be careful not to full your memory with dead data.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial allocation should be done with `malloc` or `calloc` instead of `realloc`; otherwise, your initial pointer argument needs to be `NULL`:

```
char ***tas = malloc( (i+1) * sizeof *tas );
```

or

```
char ***tas = calloc( i+1, sizeof *tas );
```

or

```
char ***tas = realloc( NULL, (i+1) * sizeof *tas );
```

or

```
char ***tas = NULL;
tas = realloc( tas, (i+1) * sizeof *tas );
```

You're pretty close otherwise - just lose the extraneous casts.

```
tas[i] = calloc( 2 * sizeof *tas[i] );
```

and

```
tas[i][0] = calloc( lenKey + 1, sizeof *tas[i][0] );
tas[i][1] = calloc( lenValue + 1, sizeof *tas[i][1] );
```

As always, check the result of every `*alloc` call.